# Contar linhas do dataframe com string de acordo com a posição no texto Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, pandas

Tenho um dataframe com uma coluna de texto, como a seguir:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([["1", "texto com PALAVRA frAse PARAGRAFO", True, "foo"],
                   ["2", "texto com palavra Paragrafo", False, "foo"],
                   ["3", "texto com Frase paragrafo", True, "foo"],
                   ["4", "texto com FRASE", True, "foo"],
                   ["5", "texto com frase", True, "foo"],
                   ["6", "frase", True, "foo"],
                   ["7", "texto", False, "foo"],
                   ["8", "texto com paRAgrafo", False, "foo"]],
                  columns=["id", "texto", "col1", "col2"])
```

Quero contar todas as linhas em que, por exemplo, "frase" ocorre antes de "palavra" ou "paragrafo"; isto é, considerando que o que aparece "primeiro" é mais relevante no contexto, se fossem conjuntos, desconsideraria as "interseções" e teria:

- linhas com "palavra": 2
- linhas com "frase": 4
- linhas com "paragrafo": 1

Pode ter mais texto antes --- por exemplo, "texto" e "com" não interessam/interferem ---; e, claro, preciso desconsiderar maiúsculas e minúsculas na hora da contagem.

Com `str.contains`, não leva em conta a "posição":

```
df_filter = df[df['texto'].str.contains('frase',case=False)]
len(df_filter)

5
```

Como fazer então?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode criar uma função que retorna `True` se um determinado `alvo` aparece antes de `outros` termos em um `texto` :

```
def veio_antes(texto, alvo, outros):
    texto = texto.lower()
    alvo = alvo.lower()

    if alvo in texto:
        texto_antes = texto.split(alvo)[0]

        for o in outros:
            if o.lower() in texto_antes:
                return False

        return True

    return False
```

Uma função lambda que passa os argumentos necessários para `veio_antes` pode ser [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)eada para os elementos da coluna do seu dataframe que contem os textos de interesse e a série resultante pode ser [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html)ada para indicar a quantidade total de vezes que um alvo aparece antes dos outros termos. Se você quiser fazer isso para todos os termos de uma lista, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
alvos = ["palavra", "frase", "paragrafo"]

for alvo in alvos:
    outros = [a for a in alvos if a != alvo]
    veio_antes_map = lambda x: veio_antes(x, alvo, outros)
    print('linhas com "{}": {}'.format(alvo, sum(df["texto"].map(veio_antes_map))))
```

Saída:

```
linhas com "palavra": 2
linhas com "frase": 4
linhas com "paragrafo": 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom pelo que entendi da sua pergunta você esta querendo verificar a ordem em que as palavras acontecem no texto, bom eu vou considerar que você tem as palavras quais quer verificar a ocorrência.

fiz um exemplo que pode ajudar você a criar a logica que se aplica melhor ao seu código:

```
frase = 'Frase para testar'

def verificar_qual_palavra_vem_antes(frase, p1, p2):

    frase = frase.lower()

    frase_partida = frase.split()

    posição_palavra_um = frase_partida.index(p1)

    posição_palavra_dois = frase_partida.index(p2)

    if posição_palavra_um < posição_palavra_dois:
        return 'a palavra 1 veio primeiro'

    else:
        return 'a palavra 2 veio primeiro'
```

**Explicando o código**

O funcionamento dele é bem simples, foi criada uma função que faz essa verificação de posições com os parâmetros Frase - palavra 1 e palavra 2

a primeira coisa que a função faz e usar a função built-in do Python `lower()` que consistem em transformar toda a string em caixa baixa

logo após é utilizado o `split` para dividir todas as palavras em um lista

e assim por final verificar o endereço de cada palavra na lista

então se o endereço da palavra 1 for menor que endereço da palavra 2 ja tem a ordem que ocorre as palavras